# cap deploy:setup giving a (Errno::ETIMEDOUT: Operation timed out - connect(2))

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-ec2, osx-lion, capistrano

I have been trying to deploy a simple rails3 app from my mac(os lion)to an amazon ec2 instance, using capistrano. When I do a **cap deploy:setup**, I get a **connection failed for: http://ec2-xxx-xx-xx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com/ (Errno::ETIMEDOUT: Operation timed out - connect(2))**

Here is my config/deploy.rb

```
set :application, "paperclip_sample_app"
set :deploy_to, "/mnt/#{application}"
set :deploy_via, :copy
set :scm, :git
set :repository,  "."

default_run_options[:pty] = true 
set :location, "http://ec2-xxx-xx-xx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com/"

role :web, location                          # Your HTTP server, Apache/etc
role :app, location                          # This may be the same as your `Web` server
role :db,  location, :primary => true # This is where Rails migrations will run
#role :db,  "your slave db-server here"

set :user, "root"
ssh_options[:keys] = [File.join(ENV["HOME"], ".ssh", "id_rsa")]
```

I have also enabled ssh on the mac by going to 'System Preferences'. Under ‘Internet & Networking’, ‘Sharing’ icon and checking the ‘Remote Login’ option.

Also the security groups on the ec2 instance has the port 22 enabled. As a result I am able to ssh into the instance.

Is there anything that I am missing? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to change

```
set :location, "http://ec2-xxx-xx-xx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com/"
```

to

```
set :location, "ec2-xxx-xx-xx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com"
```

This fixed the problem.